# Socket.io with PHP MySQL - notification system

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, socket.io

I have yet to find any information on how to use PHP/MYSQL and WebSockets, or rather socket.io.

I've installed socket.io and node, but I have no idea how to get data from the database and display it. I am trying to create a notification system, so all I need is the number of new notifications.

Basically I want to get data from the database that is new. I can totally create the query for this based off of a "datetime" or a "has_seen" column, returning a numeric value.

Thanks.

Comment: So you have the query, I'm confused what the problem is. Send the data via the socket to the clients? You should be a bit more specific :)

Comment: What? I said I'm trying to get the data from the database and display it... meaning live...

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. If you'd like to use PHP you'll need to create an endpoint or API that you can make a request to that then goes to your database to fetch data. But... it's a strange way to do things. Your best bet is using something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql to talk to your database directly without using PHP.

Comment: It's a php based system, definitely can't change that now. Are you saying to make a JSON object? Like I fully know how to make json api.

Comment: How are you using socket.io?

Comment: I've never used it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130162/discussion-between-jordan-s-and-christopher-web).